# i want to make a wave texture in surface?

Tags: texturing, materials

[image]

i want to make something like this orange cube how can I make one?

Comment: you could use 3 materials, one for the bottom, one for the sides, one for the top, for the top use a wave texture and bend it a bit with a noise?